# app.get is not working in express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();


router.get('/add-product',(req, res, next)=>{
    res.send('<form action="/try" method="POST"><input type="text" name="title"><button type="submit">Sub,it</button> </form>');

});
```

package.json
 "dependencies": {

```
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",

"express": "^4.17.1",

"funding": "^1.0.9"
```

It shows the error "unresolved function or method get()"
I even install express and body-parser

Comment: it would have been better if you put the actual output from your terminal

Answer (score 0):

You should use `express` instead of `express.Router()`

```
let router = express();
```

Comment: i did but same issue

Comment: `(req, res, next)` should be `(req, res)`

Comment: i try this also it not detect .get

Answer (score 0):

If example will not help you please specify you app starting file

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

const routerProducts = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
routerProducts.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})

// define the add-product route
routerProducts.post('/add-product', function (req, res) {
  res.send('products create')
})

// define the get-product route
routerProducts.get('/get-product', function (req, res) {
  res.send('products get')
})
app.use('/products', routerProducts )
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
```

call GET: http://127.0.0.1:3000/products/get-product